# ISpProperties for ISpRecognizer instanance

Tags: voice-recognition

I would like to set  ISpProperties for an ISpRecognizer instanance.

[ISpProperties list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) have a list of properties I would like to modify, specifically SPPROP_RESPONSE_SPEED. But I don't know how to do this syntaxly.

```
CComPtr<ISpRecognizer> m_cpRecognizer;  // object type

HRESULT hr = S_OK;
hr = m_cpRecognizer.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpInprocRecognizer);  // create an instance
```

Now how can I now use ISpProperties to modify m_cpRecognizer properties now. Specifically modify SPPROP_RESPONSE_SPEED property.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work

`m_cpRecognizer->SetPropertyNum(SPPROP_RESPONSE_SPEED,600);`

this will set response time to 600ms.